# Proof of very simple absolute value inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I was wondering how to prove this. It always appears to be true when I plug in values.

$a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\\a\lt b\lt c$

Prove $\forall a,b,c : \left|a + b\right| \space\lt \left|a + c\right|$

Comment: It is N instead of R?

Comment: It is false, in $\mathbf{Z}$, therefore in $\mathbf{R}$. In $\mathbf{N}$ it is trivial, and independant of the position of $a$ wrt $b$ and $c$.

Comment: I meant $\mathbb{N}$, but then generalized to $\mathbb{Z}$ somehow, and forgot $\mathbb{N}$ would be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

It's false. Consider $a=-2$, $b=-1$, $c=0$, then 
$$3=|{-}2-1|\not<|-2+0|=2$$

Answer (score 1):

This is false. $a = -100, b=-1$ and $c=1$.